# Changing data type of a 3rd party react component property?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that works fine but one of the props is type "string" and I would like to pass a component or simply make the data type "any". Is there a way to do this?

To make this more clear, I am trying to modify the behavior of a third-party class. This is in this case very safe and I have changed the 3rd party code directly but it is much better, if possible in Typescript, to inherit and in the inherited class, change the data type of the prop so that I can, instead of simply displaying text, display, for example, a list.

Comment: Your question is lacking clarity. Can you add more details to your question?

Comment: If the third party library component is expecting a string, you should pass it a string. You may run into unexpected behaviour if you pass it a component. To answer your question though, I don't think there's anyway to adjust typed definitions of a third party library

Comment: @paulosullivan22: i know exactly what will happen -- i am asking how it can be done without directly changing the 3rd party library itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, imo passing in type `any` usually defeats the purpose of using Typescript in the first place. The way I understand it , you have two options:

1. Separate the props: have a prop of type `string` and another of type `ReactNode` since it is a component you are planning on passing in.
2. If for some reason it has to be a single prop, use `string | ReactNode` as its type. Although I would recommend option 1 over this.

Thinking even further, you might want to consider not passing a component as a prop at all(for performance reasons). Designing your components such that you can work with doing regular ES6 `import` to get in a component would be much much better, but again this depends on your usage and design.